# Flatlist inside SectionList showing error in React Native

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am learning React native by building a delivery app and I would like to display items on my home screen using `sectionlist` or whatever component that works best. I have two sections: one is called `Hot Deals` and the second one is called "Newly Added Meals". I would like the Second items to be shown only when the user scrolls down towards the screen while the first section moves up. That is exactly what `sectionList` does. The challenge I have now is that the two sections have different styling. So, how do I achieve this in react native? I want the two sections to have different styling. On the basics, the first list would be displayed in an Horizontal form while the last list would be displayed in a vertical form.
Here is my data:
`

```
   const sectionData =[
     

    {
    title: 'Hot Deals',
    data:[[
        {
            id: 1,
            food: 'ChickenLap',
            description: 'Simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has   been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged',
            image: "https://res.cloudinary.com/blognodeapi/image/upload/v1670174078/chickeneat/pexels-  %E7%B4%A0%E6%9D%90%E7%8E%8B%E5%9B%BD-footage-kingdom-13823476_ki08p4.jpg",
            price: 1200
        },


   ]


 const recent =[

{
    id: 6,
    food: 'Smart Noodles3',
    description: 'Simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged',
    image: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/blognodeapi/image/upload/v1670175383/chickeneat/pexels-lukas-1309593_pydyhi.jpg',
    price: 2700
    },

  ]
```

This is how I displayed them so far:
`

```
  <SectionList style={{width: '100%'}}

   sections={sectionData}


 renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}})=> (
         <>
            <Text style={homePageStyles.homePageSubViewText2}>
                 
               {title}
             </Text>

        </>       

        )}

    renderItem={({item, index, section})=>  (
              <>     
          <FlatList
            data={item}
             renderItem={({item})=>(
               <HomePageCard data={item}
                 
                  />
                  
                )}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
              />         

        <Text style={[homePageStyles.homePageSubViewText2, ]}>
                  Newly Added Meals
                </Text>
                  <FlatList
                  
                    data={recent}
                    renderItem={({item})=>(
                      <RecentPostCard data={item}
                      
                      />
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                  />
          
              </>

          )}
            
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
            
          />
      />
```

It works exactly how I want it to work. I can style the sections differently using the flatList. However, it is showing me this error on that screen:
 `A VirtualizedList contains a cell which itself contains more than one VirtualizedList of the same orientation as the parent list. You must pass a unique listKey prop to each sibling list.`

Though it is working and displayed on the screen, but this error shows as alert. How best can I go about this?

I have shown my codes that I have tried to implement by using `flatList` inside `sectionList`

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem by adding `listKey` and passed the item id to it within the `flatList`